# Content(image) goes out of parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried to do zoom effect using html, css and Javascript but the image goes out of the parent div after zooming the content.

After clicking zoomin button the image will go out of the div and the first image will cut from the beginning.

```js
var factor = 1;

function funZoomOut() {
  if (factor > 0.5) {
      factor = factor - 0.1;
      var p = document.getElementById("divArea");
      p.setAttribute("style", "transform: scale(" + factor + ");");
  }
}
function funZoomIn() {
  if (factor < 1.3) {
      factor = factor + 0.1;
      var p = document.getElementById("divArea");
      p.setAttribute("style", "transform: scale(" + factor + ");");
  }
}
```

```css
.demoCss {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 470px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid red;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.test {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>
  <div>
    <button id="btn1" value="submit" onclick="funZoomOut();" style="position:relative; z-index:1;">ZoomOut</button>
    <button id="btn1" value="submit" onclick="funZoomIn();" style="position:relative;z-index:1;">ZoomIn</button>
  </div>
  <div class="demoCss">
    <div id="divArea" class="test">
      <div>
          <img src="Images/2.jpg" alt="image" height="150px" width="150px" id="img1" />
      </div>
      <div>
          <img src="Images/article-1.jpg" alt="image" height="150px" width="150px" />
      </div>
      <div>
          <img src="Images/article-1.jpg" alt="image" height="150px" width="150px" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It goes out of the containing `div` because the [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) (what `transform(scale())` takes as the starting point for the transformation) is set at the center of the images by default.

If you change it to be in the top-middle, the images will be scaled from top to bottom:

```
.test {
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}
```

```js
var factor = 1;

function funZoomOut() {
  if (factor > 0.5) {
    factor = factor - 0.1;
    var p = document.getElementById("divArea");
    p.setAttribute("style", "transform: scale(" + factor + ");");
  }
}

function funZoomIn() {
  if (factor < 1.3) {
    factor = factor + 0.1;
    var p = document.getElementById("divArea");
    p.setAttribute("style", "transform: scale(" + factor + ");");
  }
}
```

```css
.demoCss {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 470px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid red;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.test {
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <button id="btn1" value="submit" onclick="funZoomOut();" style="position:relative; z-index:1;">ZoomOut</button>
    <button id="btn1" value="submit" onclick="funZoomIn();" style="position:relative;z-index:1;">ZoomIn</button>
  </div>
  <div class="demoCss">
    <div id="divArea" class="test">
      <div>
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/300/?1" alt="image" height="150px" width="150px" id="img1" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/300/?2" alt="image" height="150px" width="150px" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/300/?3" alt="image" height="150px" width="150px" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    .demoCss {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 470px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid red;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.test {
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transitions: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
```

Comment: Why should it be done this way? Some explanation will help the person asking the question.

Answer (score -2):

Your div area/container should have overflow hidden i.e.

```css
.demoCss {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: So? This will just remove the scrollbar and the content will still be cut out, without any possibility of viewing it. Downvoted